# how to open pdf file from internal cache dir jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin

Iam trying to open a saved pdf file from the internal cache dir.
In the "old" way my code looked liked this.

In jetpack compose i can use this part of code, the pdf is beeining created and i can see it in the device explorer. But how can i display the pdf on screen ?

```
    fun decodeTestPdfString(pdf_string:String, context:Context) {

        //make FileOutPutStream
        var fos: FileOutputStream? = null

        try {
            if (pdf_string != null) {
                f = File(context?.cacheDir, "testFile" + ".pdf")
                f!!.createNewFile()

                fos = FileOutputStream(f)
                val decodedString: ByteArray = Base64.decode(pdf_string, Base64.DEFAULT)
                fos.write(decodedString)
                fos.flush()
                fos.close()


            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos = null
            }
        }



        val path: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, context!!.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", f!!)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf")
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)



        try {
            startActivity(intent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {

        }


    }
}
```

But the last step (try intent) is giving an issue.
The file is created in the cache dir, i can see it.

Comment: Which issue that would be? And why dont your catch blocks contain the usual code? And code to inform the user if there is a catch?

Comment: `But how can i display the pdf on screen ?` What do you mean? ACTION_VIEW is for letting another app handle your pdf file.

Comment: the pdf reader did not open, solved. it has to be startActivity(context, intent, options:null)

Answer (score 2):

To open the pdf reader:

```
startActivity(context, intent, options:null)
```